# Does "Helper Grid" feature in Revolution Slider 6?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, slider, revolution-slider

I did the Revolution Slider update and started using version 6. However, I could not find the "Helper Grid" and "Snap to Layers" features that I used many times before. Do you know anything about this feature?